# Potential issue when using Express without Jade

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

I'm trying to use Express for my project, and the recommended way for views is using Jade template engine like this:

```
/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});
```

but I don't want to rewrite my existing HTML file, so I use `sendfile` like this:

```
/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.sendfile("./views/hello.html");
});
```

and it work just fine!

But my question is, is there some potential issue that I didn't notice if I use `sendfile` to replace `render`? Like performance or security issue?

And if there isn't, then why the recommended way is to use Jade?

Comment: you can't set the variables in the served pages this way. So you are just serving static pages, nothing wrong with it if thats your usecase

Comment: Where is it recommended that you'd use Jade?

Comment: Because it's default in the code after I install Express, or maybe I'm too intuitive?

Comment: @XRX you mean you're using `express-generator`? That tries to cater for users that aren't yet very experienced with Express, and even though Jade is the default it can also generate code for other templating engines.

Comment: @robertklep Actually I'm using WebStorm IDE to create project automatically, and as I know it **is** using `express-generator`. I'm the user that aren't yet very experienced with Express like you said. Most of my views are static pages, do you have other way recommended to deal with it? It would be nice if you can give me some key word!

Comment: @XRX [_"Serving static files in Express"_](http://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html) might be a good start =D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There no issue about sending directly an HTML files. It will be a little faster to sending directly HTML because jade files need to be compiled into HTML before sending.

Jade is recommended if you need dynamic templating (like php, jsp...) to generate dynamic pages. If your HTML works only with Ajax you don't need jade at all.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO I don't think there are issues when sending html and not using a template engine. I think they are only recommending to use template engine is because it's much easier for developers to create a bear-bone of the html structure **plus** you can do a lot more with template engines (e.g. if statements, loops). But please bear in mind that you should also add some security to your app like `helmet` and `cors`.